# Multiselect picklist popup broken after rerender - a Salesforce bug?

Tags: visualforce, multi-select, platform-bug

When rerendering some multiselect picklist (or any of it's ancestors), some strange things happen with the floating multiselect popup - it's collapsed, the list appears twice (see picture). It seems like it get's loaded for the second time, without being flushed. It gets even worse when you rerender once again.

The code is extremely simple, just a pageblocktable with name and some multi picklist. After cancel button is pressed, some null action is performed, and table is rerendered.
Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

EDIT:
the code (nothing interesting here, `cancelc` just returns null):

```
<apex:page controller="pickController">
    <apex:form> 
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton id="cancelEditing" action="{!cancelc}"  value="cancel" rerender="pb"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cars}" var="c">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputField  value="{!c.options__c}">
                   <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" />
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I feel like your multi picklist doesn't have enough space to expand. Just inspect element and try to adjust the width. This way you may fix this issue.

Comment: Please put some code here, I don't think we can just guess what is source of your problem :)
But if i need to guess it is either CSS (some custom class?) or rerender(do you use standard controller / is it dependend picklist?) related

Comment: Ratan, it has a lot of space! Moreover, the list shouldn't appear twice, it looks just fine before rerender.
@ArturKępczyński there's really nothing there. As I said, it's just pageblocktable and command button that perform null action and rerenders the table.

Comment: @BartJuriewicz start with simple stuff - disable inline editing and check your cars getter, then check if you still have this problem.

Comment: @ArturKępczyński when inline editing is disabled, it's not possible to display multiselect edit popup - which (broken popup) appears to be the essence of the bug.

Comment: @BartJuriewicz it is when you use inputField - the point of this is to check if there is some kind of conflict betweene table and inline in this case

Comment: @ArturKępczyński input field for multiselect picklist doesn't produce popup (broken popup), but just a flat multi-picklist input which works fine after rerender (just tried it to make sure).